# Preprocess embossed datamatrix

Tags: ios, image-processing, computer-vision, datamatrix

I need to read data matrices which are embossed into metal stripes. For this I need to preprocess the video stream or pictures in order to have common data matrix scanner SDKs scan that code.

Is there a common way or technique to preprocess this kind of embossed code or text? One thing making this harder is the fact that the code has to be readable from both sides, embossed in and out.

[image: Example]

Comment: The solution is to take proper images...  consider leaving industrial machine vision to professionals. you might get away with detecting white blobs in this case but it's unlikely you'll get a robust and reliable  solution which will cause a lot of expensive trouble

Comment: another simple and most likely best solution is to use a DMC reader as Cognex, Keyence and others produce them. there is no way you can beat their performance and they are cheap compared to your own solution.

Comment: Thank you. We will consider going for such external device solutions. There are very performant and super easy to use data matrix frameworks for mobile, but they all lack support when it comes to scanning non-black&white codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

We found a very nice performing smartphone-only solution which works out of the box with such hard-to-read codes. It also works reliable and very fast in a warehouse environment.

For anyone interested, here it is: http://www.i-nigma.com/ (requires a license)

So you should never listen to people posting negative comments minutes after a question was asked. ;)